# How to set the max number of CPU/cores to run BERT as service?

Tags: nlp, numbers, cpu, bert-language-model

I can install and run BERT model as described in https://github.com/hanxiao/bert-as-service

It will take all the CPUs on the Linux machine when it runs, but I'd like to have it run on only 50 CPUs of the Linux server.

Can set I the max number of CPU/cores to run BERT model?